# TimeSpan between two DateTimes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to find out the time span between two dates.

What I have this so far:

```
 dim start as DateTime = now
 dim stop as DateTime = now
 dim span as TimeSpan = stop.Subtract(start)
```

But I don't the the correct answer.

Comment: That's how you'd do it... What are you seeing? What is wrong about it?

Comment: Date.Now subtract Date.Now = what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Well, if its faster than the accuracy of the timer, then it'll be 0.

Comment: it doesnt give me the difference it just returns the same time as the stopped time but in militar time like for example lets say its 4:00pm it returns 16:00

Comment: Did you try putting other dates in and check the span variable for the various properties?

Comment: it doesnt even return zero

Comment: well i dont want for dates i only need for the hour minutes and seconds

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx pick a property.

Comment: I really don't follow this at all. [`span.Hours` doesn't work for what reason?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02c79d34.aspx)

Comment: Uh... the code as posted won't compile with the reserved word stop being used as a variable name.  When fixed the answer is zero, or close to it depending on whether or not the process is interrupted between the two assignments.  To see any number other than zero will require an examination of the Ticks property of the TimeSpan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the time elapsed since Jan 1, 2013:

```
Dim start as DateTime = #1/1/2013#
Dim stop as DateTime = Now
Dim elapsed As TimeSpan = start.Subtract(stop)

Console.Write(elapsed.Days & " days, " & elapsed.Hours & " hours, " & elapsed.Minutes & " minutes, " & elapsed.Seconds & " seconds.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me.

E.g.

```
Dim startTime As DateTime = New DateTime(2013, 6, 12, 22, 45, 0)

Dim endTime As DateTime = New DateTime(2013, 6, 12, 22, 50, 0)

Dim span As TimeSpan = endTime - startTime
```

Result: 00:05:00

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **"stop"** , **"end"** as Variable .. This should be works (tested on VS2005)

```
dim start as DateTime = now
dim stops as DateTime = now
dim span as TimeSpan = stops.Subtract(start)
```